# Please Help Me With My Footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm using Dreamweaver to edit a template that I got for my new business website. I'm having a problem with the footer and I'm not sure if it's an HTML issue, a CSS issue, or an I'm just an idiot issue. No matter what I do the footer extends down too far. Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

http://tinypic.com/r/t9ccbn/4

Also, I would like the links to line up with the column above it like the contact info and the copyright info do. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div>
      <div id="links">
        <div class="showroom">              
              <p><br>
                9501 W. Sahara Ave. #2082
              <br> Las Vegas, NV 89117
                <br> 702-409-5373<br>
                  <a href="index.html">info@briarpatchfurniture.com</a>
          </p>
          </div>


        <ul class="navigation">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html"> Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

```
        <p id="footnote">
            © Copyright TIBISI, Inc 2013. All Rights Reserved.
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
/*------------------------------ FOOTER ------------------------------*/
#footer {
background-color: #e2b241;
border-top: 1px solid #fff;
padding: 28px 0 14px;
}
#footer p {
color: #4b3a33;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
margin: 0;
}
#footer > div {
width: 940px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 10px;
}
#footer .posts {
float: left;
height: 300px;
width: 302px;
padding: 0;
}
#footer .posts li {
width: 276px;
margin: 0 0 30px;
padding-left: 10px;
}
#footer .posts p a {
line-height: 24px;
margin: -3px 0 3px;
}
#links {
background: url(../images/separator-dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
color: #4b3a33;
display: inline-block;
width: 940px;
padding: 0 0 20px;
}
#links h4 {
color: #241b18;
font-family: "Oswald";
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 24px;
margin: 0 0 12px;
padding-left: 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#links > div {
float: left;
background: url(../images/separator-dark-vertical.png) repeat-y left top;
height: 300px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
#links .showroom {
background: none;
width: 293px;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 15px;
}
#links .showroom h4 {
padding-left: 0;
}
#links .showroom img {
margin-bottom: 12px;
}
#links .showroom p {
font-size: 13px;
margin: 0;
}
#links .showroom p em {
color: #fff;
display: block;
font-style: normal;
margin: 0 0 20px;
}
#links .showroom p a {
color: #4b3a33;
display: block;
}
#links .showroom p a:hover {
color: #241b18;
}
#newsletter {
background: url(../images/separator-dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
width: 284px;
margin: 0 0 16px 6px;
padding: 0 0 20px;
}
#newsletter h4 {
padding-left: 0;
}
#newsletter input {
color: #4b3a33;
height: 26px;
line-height: 26px;
width: 269px;
border: 3px solid #af8112;
margin: 0 0 6px;
padding: 0 4px;
*margin-left: -6px; /** Needed for IE7 **/
}
#newsletter input.btn2 {
color: #fff;
width: 83px;
border: 0;
padding: 0px 0 2px;
}
#connect a {
display: inline-block;
height: 33px;
margin: 0 10px;
}
#connect a.facebook {
background-position: -46px -112px;
width: 33px;
}
#connect a.googleplus {
background-position: -46px -153px;
width: 34px;
}
#connect a.twitter {
background-position: -46px -194px;
width: 40px;
}
#connect a.facebook:hover {
background-position: 0 -112px;
}
#connect a.googleplus:hover {
background-position: 0 -153px;
}
#connect a.twitter:hover {
background-position: 0 -194px;
}
#footer ul.navigation {
float: right;
display: block;
line-height: 24px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 12px 0 0;
}
#footer ul.navigation li {
float: left;
margin-left: 15px;
}
#footer ul.navigation li:first-child {
margin-left: 0;
}
#footer ul.navigation li a {
color: #ab7d0f;
font: 11px/24px "Oswald";
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#footer ul.navigation li a:hover {
color: #241b18;
}
#footer #footnote {
color: #ab7d0f;
font: 11px/24px "Oswald";
margin: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/GCqfE/

Comment: Please include a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I think this is what you're asking for.
http://jsfiddle.net/GCqfE/

Comment: Is there any info that I need to add? Did I explain the problem adequately? Am I missing something that's staring me in the face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `line-height` in all of the child elements of the `footer` is causing the footer to expand downwards vertically, and without a `height` value given for the parent `div` they are free to expand. Either change the line-heights to smaller values, or prescribe a height for the parent `footer` div like so:

```
#footer {
background-color: #e2b241;
border-top: 1px solid #fff;
padding: 28px 0 14px;
height:100px;
}
```

I've updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GCqfE/1/

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the issue on the home page, but it messed it up on all of the other pages as seen here:
http://tinypic.com/r/243hkk6/4

Is there a way for me to have page specific styles, or do I need to separate the pages and treat each one as a separate project?

Comment: You should either use separate css files for different pages if they are going to be complex and markedly different, or another alternative which I prefer to use is to to try and reuse as many of the css classes as possible, and create new css elements based on my requirements (say if one page has exactly the same header as another page, the css element will be reused here)